Kubernetes pods get recreated when I reboot the ec2 instance
I am running a k8s Kubernetes deployment on ec2 instance, recently i noticed that when i restarted the instance the pods gets deleted and new ones created.
I don't know if this issue new or it was like that from the start.
How could I prevent the pods from getting recreated upon a reboot?
Update:
That is expected behavior, see comments

That is expected behavior. Make sure to use multiple instances.

is there away to prevent that?

the alternative is to not use Kubernetes. Kubernetes is supposed to work that way.

The alternative is to run the app in multiple replicas. In this case the app continues to be available even if one pod restarts.
